# Regex help needed, finding repeating patterns

Tags: javascript, regex

I have some text

```
I01:00:00:05
I01:00:00:04
I01:00:00:03
I01:00:00:02
I01:00:00:01
```

Is there a regex that will find each one?

I tried:
`var locs = txt.match(/(([A-Z]\d\d\:\d\d\:\d\d\:\d\d)+)+/);`

And it finds 5 copies of the first pattern that matches.

Is there a way to get an array with each of them in it?

Thanks

Comment: Is this text part of a larger document?  What exactly are you trying to match?

Comment: The regex pattern.  but I want to end up with all the matches, not just the first one

Comment: Write your regular expression to match a single one, instead of trying to match them all in a single expression.  Then use the `/g` flag, as noted by the answers below.

Answer (score 2):

if you include the 'g' flag at the end it should work.

```
var locs = txt.match(/(([A-Z]\d\d\:\d\d\:\d\d\:\d\d)+)+/g);
```

Comment: That did it!  Thanks very much.  I should have remembered that from my unix days

Answer (score 0):

You are simply missing the g flag on your regexp and it will find all the occurences that match the pattern.
Like so:

```
var locs = txt.match(/(([A-Z]\d\d\:\d\d\:\d\d\:\d\d)+)+/g);
```

*of course if that pattern is actually good ;)*

Answer (score 0):

Write your regular expression to match a single instance, and use the global specifier `/g` to get a collection of matches (**note the modification to regular expression**):

```
var locs = txt.match(/([A-Z]\d\d\:\d\d\:\d\d\:\d\d)/g);
```

http://rubular.com/r/L2ZNyz2yJy

Answer (score 0):

Indeed in this case the "+" sign is not necessary:

```
var locs = txt.match(/[A-Z]\d\d\:\d\d\:\d\d\:\d\d/g);
```

`locs` will be `["I01:00:00:05", "I01:00:00:04", "I01:00:00:03", "I01:00:00:02", "I01:00:00:01"]`
.